# get my file by awk - split by last occurrence

Tags: awk

awk -F

here is my file

```
a_b_1
b_c_3
c_1
```

final file

```
a_b  1
b_c  3
c    1
```

how to get my final file by awk

Comment: welcome to U&L, I formated a bit input and expected data, there are many `awk` question in this forum, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and define the output format. Do you want a tab or spaces between the two fields? Is this alignment of the second field required? What if the length is very different? Example: `a_12345678` and `foo_bar_baz_very_long_first_field_1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another `sed` approach

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)_\([0-9]\).*/\1\t\2/' file
a_b     1
b_c     3
c       1
$
```

And an `awk` solution.

```
$ awk -F_ 'NF==3{$1=$1"_"$2}{print $1"\t"$NF}' file
a_b     1
b_c     3
c       1
$
```

Comment: The `awk` solution works only if there are exactly 3 or 2 fields, it doesnt work on names like : a_b_c_d_1.
The `sed` solution works only if there are a single digit after the `_`.

Comment: thank you for your notice

Answer (score 6):

I'd use `sed` here:

```bash
sed -E 's/(.*)_/\1 /' file | column -t
```